# different results from confusionMatrix of caret package and ROC of Epi package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do classification by logistic regression. To evaluate the model, I used confusionMatrix and ROC. The problem is that the results from the two packages are different. I want to figure out which one is right or wrong.

1. my data is like:
   data name = newoversample, with 29 variables and 4802 observations.
   "q89" is predicted variable.
2. my attempt:

(1) confusion Matrix from 'caret' library

```
    glm.fit = glm(q89 ~ ., newoversample, family = binomial)
    summary(glm.fit)
    glm.probs=predict(glm.fit,type="response")
    glm.pred=rep(0,4802)
    glm.pred[glm.probs>.5]="1"
    library(caret)
    confusionMatrix(data=glm.pred, reference=newoversample$q89)
```

the result is:

```
    Confusion Matrix and Statistics

              Reference
    Prediction    0    1
             0 2018  437
             1  383 1964

           Accuracy : 0.8292          
             95% CI : (0.8183, 0.8398)
        No Information Rate : 0.5             
        P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2e-16         

              Kappa : 0.6585          
     Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.06419         

        Sensitivity : 0.8405          
        Specificity : 0.8180          
     Pos Pred Value : 0.8220          
     Neg Pred Value : 0.8368          
         Prevalence : 0.5000          
     Detection Rate : 0.4202          
       Detection Prevalence : 0.5112          
          Balanced Accuracy : 0.8292          

           'Positive' Class : 0
```

(2) ROC curve from 'Epi' library

```
    library(Epi)
    rocresult <- ROC(form = q89 ~ ., data = newoversample, MI = FALSE, main = "over")
    rocresult
```

the result is: 
[roc curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovPev.png)

as you can see, here, sensitivity is 91 and specificity is 78, which are different from the result of (1)confusion Matrix.

I cannot figure out why the results are different and which one is the correct one.

+)
If the second method(ROC curve) is wrong, please let me know how to calculate auc or draw roc curve from the first method.

please help me!

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You should plot ROC curve of the same model you built using `glm`

```r
library(ROCR)
pred <- prediction(predict(glm.fit), newoversample$q89)
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion matrix seems fine. Giving the fact that you did not define 'Positive Class' so, it was set to 0 by default.

The problem is about the ROC plot. You can still use `Epi::ROC` for the roc curve but you should use `Epi::ROC(test = newoversample$q89, stat = glm.pred, MI = FALSE, main = "over")`
In this way, the Sensitivity and specificity should be not so much different from the matrix.

When you use `ROC(form = q89 ~ ., data = newoversample, MI = FALSE, main = "over")` that means you pass a logistic regression to `form` parameter which is not the same as glm model. And in this case, you should provide values of `test` and `stat` parameters for the `ROC` function instead ([check here for more detail on Epi::ROC](https://rdrr.io/cran/Epi/man/ROC.html)).